# Evaluating this $\sum ^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ with contour integration

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

This is obviously easy to solve with the Taylor series formula, but I wanted to solve it with contour integration.
$$
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=2.
$$
So what I did is this
$$
\begin{split}
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n & 
= \pi \sum^\infty_{n=0}\left[ \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{2^z \tan( \pi z)} ,\ n\right)\right]\\
& = \pi \oint_C \frac{1}{2^z \tan( \pi z)} \, dz
\end{split}
$$

[image: Contour C]

So
$$
\begin{split}
\pi \oint _{C}\frac{1}{2^z \tan( \pi z)} \, dz
&=  \pi \left[\int_A +\int_B +\int_C\right]\\
&=  \pi \left[\int_A +\int_B +i\right] \\
\\
\therefore \sum^\infty_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \pi \left[\int_A +\int_B +i\right]
\end{split}
$$

From the looks of things the integral across $A$ should be zero. But on wolfram alpha, the integral across $b$ diverges! So that's a real problem! I'm not sure if this is a good contour for this contour integral, but I have to include all of the poles on the right side of the reals (including zero though).

So any help solving the infinite sum with contour integration would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally one uses more complicated complex analysis techniques if they are simpler than directly computing the series at hand... Integrating your proposed function does not seem an easy task, whatever the contour.

Comment: But it is right, is it not? That is, what I have done should yield the right answer?

Comment: How exactly is $A$ defined? Is it supposed to encompass all natural numbers? No such contour exists.

Comment: It's tricky because the $\tan z$ behaves flat at infinity on the imaginary axis, so it's probably doable but you have to subtract $\pm i$ at $i(\pm \infty)$ (appropriately) carefully and it gets complicated; the easier try is to replace $\tan$ with $\sin$ as $\sin $ goes exponentially fast to $\infty$ on the imaginary axis at both ends so the reciprocal goes to zero fast too, and compensate for the $\pm 1$ in the residue at integers  by doing an alternate sum; I would change the contour to two vertical lines, one slightly to the left of zero and the other going to infinity on the positive axis

Comment: another idea if you really want to do the sum without alternating it, is to still use the $\sin$ but start at $1$ and then you can use the principal branch of $(-2)^z$ where you now start from a vertical line slightly right of zero, or do the indent at zero to the right

Comment: Okay, so I like the idea of using sine instead  of tangent, but I don't understand the contour you describe.